# How to generate a number of n-bit in length

Tags: c++, algorithm, bit

I'm looking for an algorithm that allows me generate pseudo-random numbers, but.. How can I the interval of numbers of n-bits? if you have an example for c++ will be great

for example:

BigNumber random(bits 256)

how Can I get the least and the most number of 256 bits

Thanks to all guys, I found the solution

if I have n-bit, the numbers are between (2^n)/2 and (2^n)-1

Comment: In C++11, `std::uniform_int_distribution<int>` may be useful.

Comment: This is a fairly odd requirement. What problem are you really trying to solve?

Answer (score 3):

If the type of random numbers is `int`, you could use the `&` operator to mask out unnecessary bits by using a suitable bit mask, e.g. binary `00001111` for the first four bits.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int getNBitRandom( unsigned int n ) {
    return rand() % ( 1 << n );
}
```

In general you should add a check if `n` is lesser then `31`.

Comment: I think it's better to do rand() * 1.0 / RAND_MAX * (1<<n)

Comment: Even better in C++11: use `std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned>`

Comment: You might want to check that. If I call `getNBitRandom(2)`, your function will return `rand() % 4`, which doesn't fit the OP's requirements. He wants a number in the range `2^(n-1) <= x < (2^n)-1`. So `getNBitRandom(2)` should return either `10` or `11`.

Comment: @JimMischel OP added line about range `2^(n-1) <= x < (2^n)-1` after I posted my answer

Answer (score 1):

The `rand()` function returns a number between 0 and `RAND_MAX`. If n is less than the number of bits in `RAND_MAX`, you can use this:

```
rand() % (1<<n)
```

However, if n is larger than the number of bits in RAND_MAX, you'll need to generate several random numbers and combine them.

For example, if RAND_MAX is 32767 (15 bits) and you want 32 random bits you'll need the following:

```
rand() ^ (rand() << 15) ^ ((rand() & 3)<<30)
```

The first rand() returns the lowest 15 bits, the second one bits 15-29 and the last one bits 30 and 31.

Answer (score 0):

For a random number up to the size of an `int`, you can use the function below:

```
unsigned int GetRandVal(int numOfBits)
{
    static int numOfBitsInRandMax = 0;
    if (numOfBitsInRandMax == 0)
    {
        srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
        for (int randMax = RAND_MAX; randMax > 0; randMax >>= 1)
            numOfBitsInRandMax++;
    }
    int quotient  = numOfBits / numOfBitsInRandMax;
    int remainder = numOfBits % numOfBitsInRandMax;
    unsigned int randVal = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<quotient; i++)
        randVal = (randVal<<numOfBitsInRandMax)|rand();
    return (randVal<<remainder)|(rand()&((1<<remainder)-1));
}
```

For a larger random number, you can call this function several times, and store each of the returned values in an array that will represent the number. For example, if you want a 256-bit random number:

```
#define BITS_PER_INT (sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT)

unsigned int array[256/BITS_PER_INT];
for (int i=0; i<256/BITS_PER_INT; i++)
    array[i] = GetRandVal(BITS_PER_INT);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set a range like this:

```
int rangeMin = 1,
    rangeMax = 100,
    generatedNumber;

generatedNumber = rangeMin + rand() % rangeMax;
```